# Spring Cloud AWS. SQS. How to configure for FIFO queues

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-cloud, sqslistener

I am using standard setup for SqsListener.

On class level

```
@Component
```

Then on method level I have this annotation:

```
@SqsListener
```

And all works as expected, but what I noticed that there is a warning in my app log:

> io.awspring.cloud.messaging.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer:[]-**AmazonSQSBufferedAsyncClient
> that Spring Cloud AWS uses by default to communicate with SQS is not
> compatible with FIFO queues.** **Consider registering non-buffered
> AmazonSQSAsyncClient bean.**

When I checked the suggested class I found that it is [depreciated](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-sqs/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/sqs/AmazonSQSAsyncClient.java) already. So any idea how to configure spring boot for fifo queues and get rid of this message?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> AmazonSQSBufferedAsyncClient that Spring Cloud AWS uses by default to communicate with SQS is not compatible with FIFO queues. To use FIFO queues with Spring Cloud SQS it is recommended to overwrite default SQS client bean with a custom one that is not based on AmazonSQSBufferedAsyncClient.

See https://docs.awspring.io/spring-cloud-aws/docs/2.4.0/reference/html/index.html

Comment: Thank you for the response. Will try the solution.

Comment: It looks like this might be different now: [Spring Cloud AWS](https://docs.awspring.io/spring-cloud-aws/docs/3.0.0/reference/html/index.html#sqs-integration) says: _"To send messages to a Fifo queue, the options include messageDeduplicationId and messageGroupId properties. If either values are not provided, a random UUID is generated. The generated values can be retrieved in the headers of the Message contained in the SendResult object."_